# Recursion > What is the flow when you get to: return num + sumRange(num-1); }

Tags: recursion

```
sumRange(3);
function sumRange(num){ if(num === 1) return 1; return num + sumRange(num-1);  }

return num + sumRange(num-1);
```

Please explain step by step what happens here.
How does it end up returning 6? How and where does the addition take place? Is this a callstack rule I need to memorize?  *Someone who didn't get it like me..How did you finally get it?

I read all the other stackoverflow questions on recursion so not to make a duplicate. But I could not locate someone who explained it in simpler terms that I could understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this recursive function:

```
function sumRange(num){ if(num === 1) return 1; return num + sumRange(num-1);  }
```

And then you call:

```
sumRange(3);
```

What happens?

- what is sumRange(3)? num == 3, so not ===1, so return 3 + sumRange(2)
- so what is sumRange(2)? num == 2, so not ===1, so return 2 + sumRange(1)
- so what is sumRange(1)? num == 1 - hey ===1, so return 1
- now sumRange(2) can return 2 + 1 == 3
- now sumRange(3) can return 3 + 3 == 6

Comment: Thanks Hans. Is this right? >There are 2 sides to the expression, left and right. The left side is 3 and the right side is the CALL. The left cannot do anything until the call returns with a value to fill in the unknown. So the callstack is set to  3 + _____,  then 2 + _____. On the final CALL, the 1 is returned so the callstack fills the blanks. -> 2 + 1  = 3, then uses that 3 to fill in 3 + 3. Then that total of 6 gets returned to the Console. The 1st call has to wait for the 2nd call to return so it can then return & the 2nd call waits for the 3rd call to return so that it can return. yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct